# WP7 Push Notification 404 response

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

My push client sends the URI to my web service, by using the URI, from my web service, I am able to send toast notification to my app installed on Emulator. But if I use the device URI and try to send a message to the device from web service, I get 404 as response. Can anyone tell me What the issue could be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you aren't having any problems receiving and storing the URL your physical device sends to your service, and that you are sending messages to this URL, the only thing I can think of is something I noticed during testing.  On occasion, if a malformed message is sent to the URL, it appears to go into a faulted state and any subsequent message (even if well-formed) sent to the service returns a 404.

I don't know if this is expected behaviour or a bug - I resolved it by fixing the malformed messages I was trying to send, and refreshing the channel from the device.

Comment: Can you please tell me what you mean by refreshing the channel from the device ?

Comment: Basically just restarted the app to get it to refresh the channel information.  My app sent the URL to my service whenever it changed (either on a new connection, or in the ChannelUriUpdated event) so I always had the up-to-date Url

Comment: The updated URI was not sent to the web service. It works fine now, after sending the updated URI.